# What should I name my PHP class file?

Tags: php, class, naming-conventions

I have seen many different naming schemes and extensions used for PHP files that are basically just classes. Some examples:

1. myClass.php
2. myClass.class.php
3. myClass.class

What is the difference, and which is better?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no difference beyond what you see.  The ones with `.class` are helpful if you use [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and don't have a specific directory where your class files live.  Otherwise, it's entirely arbitrary.  (I used to use `ClassName.class.php`.)

Comment: thanks a trill...thats what i was lookin fo

Comment: I second that... ClassName.class.php.

Comment: Please remember that class names in PHP are (still) case insenstive. For PHP `myclass` `MyClass` and `myClass`  are all the same thing. This might get in the way of the standard spl_autoload function.

Answer (score 47):

What are your coding standards?

It’s common to start class names with a capital letter (for example: `class MyClass`). If you do this, then it follows that you would name the file `MyClass.php`. And `MyClass.class.php` works too.

`MyClass.class` is a bad idea that could allow someone to view your source code if they request that file by name. Using the `.php` extension ensures that the the user will only see the output after the file is processed by the PHP interpreter which—for a file that contains nothing but a class—is a blank page.

Finally, look into [`autoload()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), which saves you the trouble of calling `require_once` in order to load your class.

---

**Update:** With PHP coding standard [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), there is now a semi-official way to name your class files. The previous advice—to name your class file the same as the class with the `.php` extension—still stands. But now you are expected to place that class file in a subdirectory named after your class namespace; PSR-4 requires that all of your classes be contained in a namespace defined by you.

What do you get for this? Autoloading for free! If you’re using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), you can [specify the top-level directory for your classes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) and Composer will autoload them. No more `require` statements to load your classes.

If you don’t want to do this, you don’t have to: PSR-4 is a *recommendation*, not a requirement.

Comment: Nate, i've heard of the autoload...is that stable? the php.net basically calls it a last ditch effort?

Comment: Plus one for the security issue being raised with MyClass.class

Comment: I haven’t had problems with `__autoload`. The doc describes it as last chance, not last ditch. I don’t think that’s a bad thing.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but it jogged something loose in my brain that let me solve a problem that is weeks old. Essentially a syntax error, but the power of SO came to the rescue yet again. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer MyClass.php - the exact same name (including capitals) as the class.

However, if you are working on an existing project, you should use whatever naming scheme the project has.

Comment: You use the word 'Class' in your class name? I see that as just adding redundancy with no gain in clarity, since your class will be defined like `class MyClass`, or `class ProductRepositoryClass`... there's just no reason not to define the class like `class ProductRepository` and the file like `ProductRepository.php`, or what I like: `ClassProductRepository.php`. Most people however seem to prefer a file name like `ProductRepositoryClass.php` which I'm OK with but it seems less consistent with a non-redundant class definition. Having 'Class' in the file name at least identifies it at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless working on an existing project or platform, I tend to lean towards a documented set of conventions, such as Zend's: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

Plus this means you can use tools like PHP Code Sniffer to ensure everyone sticks to the convention.

Either way, Consistency is the name of the game. It makes it a lot easier for others (including yourself months from now) to get up to speed on a code base.