# Php files should have upper case?

Tags: php

I mean, if I have the class `Map` located in the `map.php` file, should I have this file as `Map.php`? 'Cause I made an autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name)
{
$CorePath = dirname(__DIR__) . '/fod/' . $class_name . '.php';  

if(file_exists($CorePath))
{
    include $CorePath;
}
});
```

now the problem is if I call: `$x = new Map();` the autoloader doesn't locate it, but if I rename as `Map.php` the autoloader locate it. Any idea?

Comment: If you're on a case-sensitive OS, you have to separate `Map` from `map` when you are working with files. This is why you generally should have lower-case file names (though nobody's to blame if you use upper-cases as well). So your function will only include if it actually exist, and if it doesn't you won't be able to use whatever is inside that file.

Comment: the question is: `Map.php` or `map.php`? I should make my files all with big letter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I name my PHP class file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209720/what-should-i-name-my-php-class-file)

Comment: @Sevengames I already answered that in the comment :) It's really opinion based, but since most operating systems are case-sensitive when working with files, you *should* stick to lowercase to avoid issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classname must be the same as the filename, as you've said. If you want to stick with the lower case filenames, then make the `$class_name` lowercase.

The function is [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtolower.php)

```
$CorePath = dirname(__DIR__) . '/fod/' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php';
```

But the file must have the same name as the class, so that the autoloader can work.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case-sensitive. So, yes, you should either use the lowercase version of $class_name to load files and use lowercase for the file names or have the class names uppercase. I would prefer the latter but this is a matter of taste.

Comment: Okay, but you suggest to have all the file with the upper case letter or lower case? Essentially: Map.php or map.php?

Comment: I would go with uppercase letters. Frameworks like Laravel also have this as basic approach, so rather Map.php

Comment: so there is no rules, personal opinion thought

Comment: yes, there is no reason to have rules for it. Just have it consistent within your project and you are fine

Answer (score 0):

Apart from everything else PHP class names (and namespaces) are **not case sensitive**. For PHP (8.1)

```
class Map {
...
}
```

and

```
class map {
...
}
```

are the same thing. Equally both `new \Map()` and `new \map()` will construct the same thing. If the class `Map` is in a class file names `Map.class.php` this will be no problem in a cases insensitive OS, (like for instance Windows, where AAMOF the NTFS *is* case sensitve!); `map.class.php` and `Map.class.php` will be equally the same thing. On a case sensitive OS/fs like Linux things will be dramatically different and care must be taken when autoloading class files as `map.class.php` and `Map.class.php` are two different things.

### Using spl_autoload_extensions()

If the now preferred autoloading with

```
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');
spl_autload_register();
```

is used there is a important thing to realize. As `spl_autoload_extensions` is made aware of the fact that class names are *not* case-sensitive it will do a mb_strtolower to every class name it encounters. Suddenly a class named `class Map` can no longer be found in a file called `Map.class.php`. It has to be named `map.class.php` because of this mb_strtolower().

### Options

There are two options.

1. ignore the PSR standard and use lower case for class name (reflecting the actual situation) and class filename.
2. apply the PSR standard naming but use all lowercase in the class filename.

Option 1) is good in a way that class name and class filename are in sync which IMO is preferable whereas Option 2) might confuse other developers reading your code. But neither is ideal. Btw. (PSR)[https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/] seems to ignore this fact of default PHP life and suggest their own class loader.